# Is the phrase "the ease at which / the ease by which ..." correct

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-order, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

**1) ** Is it correct to follow "ease" with "at which" such as in  "The **ease at which** you can carry this bag depends on the angle you hold it from"

**2)** Does anyone have a good source recommendation for the rules of using different nouns with along with the word "which"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ease at which** is used fairly frequently in AmE as found here in *Lloyd's Penny Weekly Miscellany of Romance and General Interest* - 1843  [google book](https://books.google.com/books?id=z7ZHAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22ease%20at%20which%22&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q=%22ease%20at%20which%22&f=false)

> The perfect **ease at which** Sir Skiffington evidently felt himself ...

and

> "The **ease at which** you can carry this bag depends on ... "

Comment: That 1843 quotation refers to Sir Skiffington feeling himself to be _at ease_, i.e. comfortable. We normally perform an action, e.g. carrying a bag, _with ease_.

Comment: Yes, I noticed @Kate Bunting, thanks. So in that case, it would be "The ease with which you can carry this bag", right?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant to imply.